# Confused by the example code which adds new instance methods to types

Tags: swift, function, extension-methods

The following code snippet is copied from the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) where it is used to demonstrate how to use the Extensions to add method to existing types.

```
extension Int {
    func repetitions(task: () -> Void) {
        for _ in 0..<self {
            task()//what's going on here?
        }
    }
}

3.repetitions { //why I don't have to call as `repetitions()`
    print("Hello!")
}
```

**Question:** The question is not asking how the extinsion extens. I just feel a bit confused about this code, why it looks like so? why use `task()` inside function body? Where it comes from? for the line `3.repetition` why not write it as `3.repetition()`

Thanks a lot

Comment: `task` is the name of a function. `task()` calls that function.

Comment: @matt Q1: you mean the function like "print("hello!")"? Q2: Does it has anything to do with the `task` inside (task: () -> Void). Thanks a lot.

Comment: It _is_ that `task`. The parameter passed into this function is a function. We are allowed to give our parameter any name we want. We call it `task`.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your help")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repetitions` is a function that accepts as its parameter a function and calls that function several times.

To call `repetitions`, we could say (note, this is Swift 3):

```
func sayHi() {
    print("Hello")
}
3.repetitions(task:sayHi)
```

But why define an extra name `sayHi`? Instead we use an anonymous function:

```
3.repetitions(task:{print("Hello"})
```

But in that case we are allowed to omit the parenthesis in this call to `repetitions` and use *trailing* syntax:

```
3.repetitions{print("Hello")}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why use task() inside function body?

The `task` parameter is defined as a closure aka an anonymous function:

```
task: () -> Void
```

This says that the function expects another function as a parameter, one which takes no arguments and returns no values.

Calling `task()` invokes that function which is passed in.

> for the line 3.repetition why not write it as 3.repetition()

Search for "Trailing Closure Syntax". If the last argument to a Swift function is a closure, you can attach it to the call outside of the `()` argument list.
Or in other words, this is exactly the same:

```
3.repetitions(task: {
  print("Hello!")
})
```

(whether you have to use `task:` as the keyword argument depends on whether you use Swift 2 or 3.